# How to update youtube-dl using terminal

Tags: 14.04, updates, youtube-dl

I use youtube-dl command for downloading the videos from Youtube. But now it is not working. So I thought it need to be update. I used `youtube-dl -U` to update, but they show the following message:

[image: message shown by Terminal]

So what should now I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To update from command line, use the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 4):

To update type the following in command line

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: this does not work